# How to query the root element from importURI?

Tags: xtext, acceleo

I'm developing a DSL, and I'm using Xtext's `importURI` attibute to deal with imports. It is working fine in the editor, but I don't know how to query the root element of the resource from the `importURI`s - which are just strings (later, in Acceleo). What would be the best way to do that?

P.S. My DSL allows only explicit imports. Also I have 2 meta-models : First one's root element is *Alg*, and the second one imports Alg(s) (root element - *Root*).

Right now, I have a Service that "goes" through all elements and return the root element of the imported resources. I think there is no need to go through the whole tree just to find something that could be deduced from import statements.

**So, what would be the `List<Alg> getAlgs(Root root)` java method to retrieve all *Alg* roots?**

**Grammar**:

```
Root returns Root:
    {Root} (name = QualifiedName ":")?
    (importStatement += ImportStatement)*
    [...];

ImportStatement:
    'import' importURI=STRING;

[...]
```

**Acceleo**:

```
[query public getAlgRoot(arg0 : Root) : Sequence(Alg)
    = invoke('org.example.tojava.services.AlgpRootService', 'getAlgs(org.example.mydsl.model.Root)', Sequence{arg0}) 
/]
```

Comment: if there imported files are not used and you want to load them directly you have to resolve the uris (importUriresolver) and look up / load the resources in the resourceset yourself. a import is not a include

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Thank you, I think this is exactly what I need. Could you please write me an example of how to load resources from importURI string?

Comment: i dont have any snippet at hand. 
1 use ImportUriResolver to resolve
2 use resourceset.getResource + resource.load

Answer (score 0):

Usually the STRING in importURI should be a URI that points to the resource you wish to import, which makes its elements accessible for cross-references in your original grammar. So I would say you are simply missing the cross-reference to Alg objects.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. In the concrete syntax I can refer to objects in imported resources. My problem is after this stage - when I have the instance model - I just don't know how to retrieve from imports the root element.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: I re-wrote the question..." what would be the List<Alg> getAlgs(Root root) java method to retrieve all Alg roots? "